# Deploy console webjob app to azure App service containing a webapi using azure devops pipelines

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have 2 webAPI’s written in .net core 2.2.The 2 web api’s are triggered by web jobs which are console Apps in .netcore 2.2. They are all different projects and in different repositories in Azure DevOps.

I am trying to deploy the web Api's together with the webjob into 2 web app services(eg: WebApi1 + Web job1 into App service1 and WebApi2 + Web job2 into App service2) in Azure using the Azure DevOps build and release pipelines.

I am able to add the webjobs manually into App Service from Azure portal and it works fine.But I want to deploy it using Azure DevOps pipelines.

I tried different ways to publish the web jobs(console apps) with the web api in the app service, like trying to publish it to App_Data folder from Azure DevOps.

I mainly followed the blog below.

https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/deploying-dotnet-core-webjobs-to-azure-using-azure-pipelines

But when I try to publish the webjob it overwrites the web api code(all the 4 projects have seperate build/release pipelines). The webjob code gets deployed in the site/wwwroot folder rather than the site/job folder.

[image]

**My Build steps:**

[image]
[image]

**My Release steps:**

[image]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Is there a way to copy the webjobs files into the same app service without overwritting the actual webapi code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked this question a while on github repo [azure-webjobs-sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2166) but the answer didn't help me as well...

i tried the following and it worked out for me:

1. In Azure Portal navigate to: **App Service** > **Configuration** > **Path mappings** > **Virtual applications and directories**

[image]

2. In DevOps configure your build pipeline like:
   [image]
3. configure your release pipeline like:
   [image]

configure the task:

[image]

Comment: Daniel, when I deploy the webjob it still clears the wwwroot folder(what remains is the hostingstart.html file). But when I deploy the Web Api project again to same app service(with the webjob already deployed) it works. Is there a way around so that I donot have to deploy my API after the webjob? Any way to prevent the clearing of the wwwroot when deploying the webjob?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by following below steps sequentially -

1. Deploy Webjob using App Service Deploy task which has below setting for deployment method -

[image]

2. Deploy API using App Service Deploy task which has below settings -

[image]

After these two steps, API and webjob work seamlessly in same app service.